# How to supply data source instance for report viewer in code C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource, reportviewer, rdlc

I am trying to to load my ASP.NET report viewer from code, I get the following error `A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source`

Here is my code:

```
 Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
            Class_Connection.cnn.Open();


            var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TT", Class_Connection.cnn);

            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());


            var source = new ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt);

            RV_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            RV_Main.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/AllTTByLastWeek.rdlc");
            RV_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
            RV_Main.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

How can I supply the data source instance from code not in the GUI control?

Comment: Check if there's data in dt and what is the dt,TableName at runtime?

Comment: @InitK Good call, it looks like there is not any data, and I don't know why, I am not getting an error on  dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

Comment: Hey @nate .. Have you found why the data source is null? have you resolved the problem?

Comment: @Mahe I updated the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the data source in the property via GUI, in the IDE. It wouldn't work with out it, even if I set in the code behind.